# SonarQube email settings broken?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

I'm logging in to SonarQube as a user with a sonar-administrator role and want to edit the global email settings (previous settings were incorrect) and now this view is completely empty! Is there an explanation?

SonarQube version is 5.4.

[image: Empty e-mail view]

**Edit:** Here are the browser errors (Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m):

[image: Browser issue]

Comment: Anything interesting in `sonar.log` when loading this page ? Also use your browser's inspector (_Network_ tab) to see the resources loaded when accessing this page, and potential errors.

Comment: Nothing in sonar.log. I've added a screenshot from the browser inspector with some errors

Comment: have you tried loading this pages from a new box or another navigator? do you have the same problem?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem with IE 11 but I can still reproduce the issue in Chrome. This time with "Version 50.0.2661.94 m". There seems to be a timing issue as it worked on one of the instances but not the other.